# Linq group by statement

Tags: linq, join, group-by

I have two tables 
Table 1

```
ID1   Col1_1  
1     "123"   
2     "12331"
```

Table2 (FK1 = ID1)

```
ID2   FK1   Col2_1      Col2_2
 1     1     "11"     "4.04.2012"
 2     1     "21"     "5.06.2012"
 3     1     "31"     "2.04.2012"
 4     2     "41"     "5.04.2012"
 5     2     "51"     "1.02.2012"
```

I need to join this tables, order by date(Col2_2) and group by FK1.
The result should look like

```
ID2   FK1   Col2_1       Col2_2     Col1_1
 2     1     "21"     "5.06.2012"   "123"
 4     2     "41"     "5.04.2012"   "12331"
```

Is it posible to do such request? I need to have this request in (from ... join ... group by ... select...) form.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried to do something like

    from t2 in Table2
    group t2 by t2.FK1 into group

    from gr in group
    join t1 in Table1 on ...
    select new { ... };
But the result have duplicates.

Comment: Why value "21" for `Col2_1`?

Comment: Oh, I missed the "orderby Col2_2". "5.06.2012" is the latest date for FK1="1" that's why we have corresponding value of Col2_1 = "21".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from t1 in Table1
            join t2 in Table2 on t1.ID1 equals t2.FK1
            group new { t1, t2 } by t1.ID1 into g
            let i = g.OrderByDescending(e => DateTime.Parse(e.t2.Col2_2))
                     .FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                ID2 = i.t2.ID2,
                FK1 = i.t2.FK1,
                Col2_1 = i.t2.Col2_1,
                Col2_2 = i.t2.Col2_2,
                Col1_1 = i.t1.Col1_1
            };
var results = query.ToList();
```

I've tested it with LINQ to Objects and your sample data and results are as expected.